# upgrade ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 17.04, do-release-upgrade

When I try to upgrade my desktop ubuntu 17.04 to ubuntu 17.10 I got this error message:

[image: A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.]

But my network connection works perfectly.

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt-get update`? Does that error at the end still show?

Comment: no, i got this problem " The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file. " and when i select the best server i got the same problem " No suitable download server was found, please check your network connection "

Comment: This is because the ppa does not support zesty yet. You can try changing the file according to the repo inside the directory "/etc/apt/source.list.d/" to "xenial"

Comment: I think it's a server issue, since it looks like someone just posted a duplicate question. https://askubuntu.com/q/1000765/417351

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for terminal output. Instead, paste the terminal output into your question, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor to format it properly.